# How to convert 16 bit grayscale image to 8 bit using linear mapping with libvips

Tags: libvips

I would like to convert a 16 bit grayscale image to 8 bit, where the lowest value of the 16 bit image becomes 0, and the highest becomes 255

As far I can see, I can call [vips-hist-norm](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-histogram.html#vips-hist-norm), which will map it across the full 16 bit range.

However its unclear to me how I can then convert to 8 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[vips-scale](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-conversion.html#vips-scale%5D) will perform linear mapping of current type to uchar type.